# Is it OK to have multiple media queries for each section of the page?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I learned about media queries and learned that there should be **major breakpoints** for layout dramatic changes and **minor breakpoints** for things like paddings and font-size.
but is it okay to declare multiple media queries for each section of the page?
 for example: three for the **navigation** and three for **each** section of main content
I think this would be better than changing the whole layout on 4 or 5 media queries.

Comment: It's better that you keep a small number of queries to facilitate code maintenance. Imagine that you are a new developer in the project and you have to maintain and understand all those different media queries. Not easy.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that, you could say the same of everything - don't use so many styles, don't use so much JavaScript, don't use so much HTML, it all adds to overall project complexity. In truth we have tools to help mitigate all of these things (SCSS, JavaScript components + bundlers, HTML templating, etc). If a media query is needed then use it, and find other ways to make your code easier to understand/maintain.

Comment: Sure, if it's needed, use it. But I think that you should always consider ways to minimize them by coding mobile-first, using flexbox and tunning the styles percentages for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is different for every site. If it works on your site and it isn't too complex than why not? There are no 'rules' that apply to every site. Some people don't like to use it, so they don't. And some do like it thus use it.

Answer (score 4):

why not, I do sometimes.. e.g.

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
    body {
        background: green;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 500px){
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 400px){
    body {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7dundm4r/)